# Javascript form button not submitting

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code in my main page

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadQueryResults() {
    $('#DisplayDiv').load('toaction.php');
    return false;
}
</script>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <form id="QueryForm" method="post">
            <div id="SubmitDiv" style="background-color:black;">
            <input type = "text" name="song"></input>

            <button type="submit" form="QueryForm" onclick="return loadQueryResults();">Submit Query</button>

            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="DisplayDiv" style="background-color:red;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following in my toaction.php

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
    <div id="page" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <?php
            if( isset($_POST['song']) )
            {
            $song = $_POST['song'];
            echo $song;
            }
            else
            {
            echo "form didn't submit";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is to dynamically refresh the div without reloading the page.  Which works, but the variable "song" is not passed through - so the div updates with "form didn't submit".

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How should it magically know which form to submit without you pointing it out?

Comment: lol,I know its a stupid mistake but I am pretty new to both languages so can u please expand

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't load two versions of jQuery.

Comment: Thank you...I took care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't send any parameters in your `$.load()` call. Also, `$.load()` sends a `GET` request, not `POST`. Try this:

```
function loadQueryResults() {
    $.post('toaction.php', $("#QueryForm").serialize(), function(response) {
        $('#DisplayDiv').html(response);
    });
    return false;
}
```

`.serialize()` will construct a parameter list from all the fields in the given form, similar to normal form submission (one difference is that the submit button won't be included in the parameters).

Comment: developing this further...if I have two submit buttons such as <button name="song" type="submit" value="1" form="QueryForm" onclick="return loadQueryResults();">Play Song</button>
and <button name="song" type="submit" value="2" form="QueryForm" onclick="return loadQueryResults();">Play Song</button> toaction.php doesn't pickup the value from a submit button .. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the last line of my answer, that explains it; submit buttons are only sent when the browser submits the form as a result of you clicking on it, AJAX doesn't know anything about it. If you need to include the submit button, you will have to add it to the parameters in your script. Or you could use a hidden input, and have the button click handlers fill this in.